# Visual Studio different git repos on same solution

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have a solution with 3 websites inside.
each website has his own git repo.
For some reason only the first website has the source control options.
the 2 other sites seems not to be manage with source control.
anyway to make all of them monitored and treaded by VS 2019 as under source control without merging them all to the same git repo ?

Comment: looks like VS 2019 doesn't support this :-( opened a feature request with Microsoft team.

Comment: Update - MS announce it's on the roadmap. expecting a solution in future version of VS.